# Elastic search NEST function_score dynamic filter conditions

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net

I am using function_score to calculate weight based on the filter conditions, I have so many filter conditions, is there any dynamic ways to add filters and weights accordingly?

```
var functions = new List<Func<FunctionScoreFunctionsDescriptor<ResidentialDetails>, FunctionScoreFunction<ResidentialDetails>>>();
var scaleDaysForSorting = 12d;
            functions.Add(fn => fn.Gauss(g => g.DateCreated, g => g.Scale(scaleDaysForSorting))
                                            .Weight(8.5)
                                            .Filter(f =>
                                            {
                                                return filters[term] && filters[refine] && filters[standard] && filters[imageExists];
                                            }));
            functions.Add(fn => fn.Gauss(g => g.DateCreated, g => g.Scale(scaleDaysForSorting))
                                            .Weight(8)
                                            .Filter(f =>
                                            {
                                                return filters[term] && filters[refine] && filters[standard] && filters[imageDoesNotExists];
                                            }));
            functions.Add(fn => fn.Gauss(g => g.DateCreated, g => g.Scale(scaleDaysForSorting))
                                    .Weight(7.5)
                                    .Filter(f =>
                                    {
                                        return filters[term] && filters[refine] && filters[premium] && filters[imageExists];
                                    }));
            functions.Add(fn => fn.Gauss(g => g.DateCreated, g => g.Scale(scaleDaysForSorting))
                                    .Weight(7)
                                    .Filter(f =>
                                    {
                                        return filters[term] && filters[refine] && filters[premium] && filters[imageDoesNotExists];
                                    }));
            functions.Add(fn => fn.Gauss(g => g.DateCreated, g => g.Scale(scaleDaysForSorting))
                                   .Weight(6.5)
                                   .Filter(f =>
                                   {
                                       return filters[term] && filters[refine] && filters[unclaimed] && filters[imageExists];
                                   }));
```

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic way?

Comment: I have posted just 5 types of filters with different weights, so that I can sort the documents. But actually I have 18 types filters, imagine the lines of code, I want something which can do the same result in less lines of code.

Comment: I didn't want to compare sql queries with elastic search queries, but in my case 4 lines of code solves sorting thing in SQL. If we have any dynamic way in elastic search would be much helpful.